# Should libs ands frameworks be subject to a version controlling repository?

Tags: version-control, architecture, frameworks, versioning, libraries

Our sw project uses for its build process different libs (popular as well as special ones) and a framework. The libs never change, whereas the framework could be changed from time to time to an updated version.

For extended further developing we want to use a version control system. Which of these solutions is the most elegant one:

1. The full project with all libs and the framework gets uploaded in the version control system's repository thus everyone has exactly the same files, but the use of space in the repository is enormous.
2. Only the artifacts of the project which are getting effectively changed over time (the main program) are in the repository. Used libs and the framework are stored on a central NAS. -> Files could be used for other projects, too.
3. Like 2, but everyone hast a copy of the libs and the framework on his local workspace.

For my taste solution 2 or 3 sound better, because I think that the repository should be as light as possible. What are you recommending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a matter of opinion, but my opinion is that the most important characteristic of version control is the ability to reproduce source at a particular point.  That includes libraries.  There are downsides (boost is *huge*, for example), but it guarantees that everyone gets the same code, especially in the case of obsolete or unsupported libraries.

You can have both; structure your source control so that it separates your source and your lib/framework.  People can put them in different places locally if they so choose, but everybody will have the same codebases.

Disks are cheap; time wasted trying to figure out why people aren't all seeing the same thing isn't.  The most important thing is that everyone stay in synch.